# Where do I find my gazebo installation path?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-11

I am new to gazebo and I would like to know how to find my installed path.
Please let me know.

I am using gazebo-11

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, vbalaji21. Which operating system are you using? Have you tried `which gazebo`?

Comment: As @Chuck mentioned on Linux or macOS you can use `which gazebo` to find where gazebo is installed, instead you are on Windows, you can find where gazebo is installed with `where gazebo` .

Comment: @traversaro I wasn't sure how to look it up on Windows, so thanks for that! If you want to make your comment an answer I'd be happy to upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments on Linux or macOS you can use `which gazebo` to find where gazebo is installed, instead you are on Windows, you can find where gazebo is installed with `where gazebo` .